# How to use on_child trigger of firebase for only 100 entries and continue once 100 are loaded?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database that has the following hierarchy.

[image]

The Energy monitoring node contains more that 250k childrens. What I want to do is to get the first 100 and once first 100 are downloaded on the client side the call for next 100 is sent, since calling 250k at one time will take a lot of time. What's the solution I have tried limitToLast(100) and limitToFirst(100) but none of them works and no data is received with either of the 2 commands why is that so ?

Code:

```
  firebase.database().ref('smartenergymonitoringsystem' +'/' +'Energy 
  Monitoring').limitToFirst(10).on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
  });
```

EDIT: 
[image]

I am expecting for data but none of the children are printed in console.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we have no idea if you're using the APIs correctly.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited the question by adding the code in it. Kindly have a look.

Comment: What is wrong with the code?  Please explain what it does that's different than what you expect.  Also consider that it's probably better to use `once()` instead of `on()` to get the entire page of data in a single snapshot.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am expecting for data but none of the children are printed in console. Question edited I have added the screenshot of console also.